# Is it possible to add swipe actions dynamically in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

The question is quite simple. I receive entities from API that contains property `actions` and I need to display them in a list with actions as swipe actions accordingly.

Problem is that I didn't find the way how to iterate actions in `swipeActions` modificator.

I tried something like this:

```
List {
    ForEach(entities) { entity in
        CustomCell(entity: entity)
            .swipeActions(edge: .trailing) {
                for action in entity.actions {
                    Button(action: {}) {
                        Label(action.title)
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

and it does not work.

Is it even possible to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `action` type is `Identifiable` (if not then confirm it), it can be done with `ForEach`, because `swipeActions` expects views, so it can be like

```
List {
    ForEach(entities) { entity in
        CustomCell(entity: entity)
            .swipeActions(edge: .trailing) {
                ForEach(entity.actions) { action in    // << here !!
                    Button(action: {}) {
                        Label(action.title)
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```